# malformed file name on disk to be deleted

Tags: windows-7, linux, cygwin

In my desktop folder I do have a directory called 'final_year_project_cd'. Inside that directory I do have this file with following file name.

```
final_year_project_cd/src/customers_view_window.h\n\n;\n’:
```

This is due to I'm editing files on this directory from both linux and windows machines. But I don't know why linux kernel/file system driver does allow there to name a file like this at the first place[well that's beyond my skills and capabilities to explain why or how].

The problem is , now I need to clean-up this directory from my desktop and so far I have tried following things but no success yet !

1. tried with 7-zip file manager.
2. Tried with cygwin terminal.
3. Tried with command line. "rmdir /s /q"

I still didn't tried to delete this under linux. May be that would work. Any new idea to try to delete this file under windows ?

UPDATE:

4. Have used the mv command as suggested by @Ohnana too.

Still not working.

Comment: Have you attempted a mv command to change the filename?

Comment: I tried mv command to change the file name but it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slashes in the filename pose a particular problem in Unix, but https://kb.iu.edu/d/abao suggests some different ways of deleting such files. The ultimate answer suggested was to FTP into the directory from another account (with sufficient privileges, of course) and use *mdel* to delete all files with prompting. You might also use Midnight Commander, https://www.midnight-commander.org/.

Comment: Solution regarding midnight commander does not working. It returns the error 19 , the resource is busy. Any idea what is error 19 is? And directory was not open in any other file manager or a process.

Comment: Do a complete shutdown, then open MC before any other application; hopefully, the file will be unlocked. If not, boot from USB or DVD; that should eliminate any file use issue.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try using the cygwin terminal's version of rm:

```
1) rm "final_year_project_cd/src/customers_view_window.h\n\n;\n’:"

2) rm final_year_project_cd/src/customers_view_window.h*
```

You can also attempt to use the windows command line:

```
DEL final_year_project_cd/src/customers_view_window.h*
```

Luckily, those are back slashes in your filename, so if all else fails you can delete it on Linux using the ultra-delete procedure:

```
user@host $ ls -i
####### final_year_project_cd/src/customers_view_window.h\n\n;\n’:
user@host $ find . -inum ##### -exec rm {} \;
```

What this does is you request the inode number from ls. I've marked it as ###### above. Then, you point the find command at it via the inode number and tell it to delete the bugger.